# didDiscoverPeripheral is returning less advertisementData since iOS9

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios9, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

This is a CoreBluetooth API question. I noticed that my app is getting much lower advertisementdata packets since iOS 9. Does anyone notice this and if so is that a iOS 9 bug/power-saving feature? how to work around that and make it so it returns the most advertisement data packets?

Here's my code. It should scan for all BLE packets. But the advertisementData is coming back from the delegate 1/2 as much as pre- iOS 9.0.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES};
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
```

Thanks